# Get class info of Keras' ImageDataGenerator images besides parsing filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, keras-2

I load hundres of images with `ImageGenerator` and its `flow_from_dirctory-function` from lets say two directories (two classes) in the validation directory (and test directory) with names "cats" and "dogs":

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        root_dir + '/validate',
        target_size=(img_x, img_y),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode='grayscale',
        class_mode='input',  # necessarry for autoencoder
        shuffle=False, # must be false otherwise filenames are wrong
        seed = seed)
```

After using some Keras model generation and fitting I want to debug sample images: I want to take images from the `validation_generator` and run the model on it. But I have to know in which directory the image was in the first place or with the class it was assigned to.

For plotting I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 7
x,y = validation_generator.next()
for i in range(0,n):
    image_x = x[i,:,:,0]
    #print(validation_generator.class_indices) # always shows the same
    print(validation_generator.filenames[i]) # only OK if shuffle=false
    plt.imshow(image_x)
    plt.show()
```

I could only find the possibility to parse `validation_generator.filenames[i]` and take the directory of it. Is there any other, more elegant, way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be an elegant way for an autoencoder so I post my quirky way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
n = 7
x,y = validation_generator.next()
for i in range(0,n):
    plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
    image_x = x[i,:,:,0]
    image_label = os.path.dirname(validation_generator.filenames[i]) # only OK if shuffle=false
    print(image_label)
    plt.imshow(image_x)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
validation_generator.class_indices  # ==> return: {'ants': 0, 'bees': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `class_indices` attribute is a dictionary that contains the mapping from class names to class indices, so this is indeed the same for each data example that the generator yields. You could access the label for `image_x` from `y` as follows:

```
label_x = y[i]
```

Comment: I also thought that and tried it but its output is a very big numpy array of arrays (?) like [[[1.] [1.] [1.]  ...  [1.] [1.] [1.]]

Comment: What is the shape of this array?

Comment: It is 128x128 px as my image. In fact both `x,y = validation_generator.next()` are exactly the same image.

Comment: So your generator is not actually yielding (image, label) pairs but rather (image, image) pairs?

Comment: It seems so, you can see the generator in my first posting.

Comment: Aha, your are training an autoencoder. I missed that point. In that case, I guess you will have to stick with using validation_generator.filenames[i]